# What is the best locking version control system?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, locking

I am looking to implement a source version control system at my office. We develop mobile apps and therefore have a large variety of different projects that need to be controlled. I also do not want a system that merges. This in my experience causes too many headaches and as such I want a locking system whereby only one person can work on a file at the same time. What can people recommend? I'm leaning towards [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) and TortoiseSVN on Windows but I'm not sure if it can be set to only locking and not merge.

Comment: I'm interested to see what kind of responses you'll receive.  There tends to be little fondness for locking version control around here (or much of anywhere) in times when much of the world is shifting toward the polar opposite in Git & Mercurial.

Comment: @Michael: I think what people will rather not be too fond of is the "merging is too complicated" part of the question. Still I don't see why this should be closed, IMO it doesn't meet the non-constructive criteria.

Comment: I would say that you may be in for some frustration by attempting to work with Subversion in a locking-only manner. That's really kind of against the tool. Like buying a car and then just pushing it around town from behind.

Comment: @Dylan: What is it that you dislike about decentralization and merging?

Comment: I would rather the team (in various locations) be managed in such a way so that nobody is working on the same item at the same time as someone else. And if they happen to need that particular file they can discuss with the other developer about what's happening and when it will be available. I have worked on different source control systems (mainly SourceGear Vault) and it's locking mechanism worked like a dream.

Comment: @Dylan: And how is that better than, e.g. just let two developers work on their own copy of the file and then merging their changes afterwards? This might be a headache in SVN sometimes, but it's as easy as it can be in decentralized SCMs like Git or Mercurial.

Comment: @Niklas: So what products to you recommend? I'm all for trying something out. But I hear git is complicated and not Windows friendly.

Comment: @Dylan: Both Git and Mercurial have Windows interfaces as well (TortoiseGit/msysGit, TortoiseHg). Just try it out. Mercurial should be a bit simpler than git, but in the end both can be grasped quite easily. Try to forget everything you know from SVN or CVS, that'll make it easier to understand the different workflow :)

Comment: My experience, in different organizations, is that (1) people will wind up having to make changes to the same file, and (2) they typically are making changes to different parts of the same file.  (1) means that, if merges are not automated, they're manual, which is worse.  (2) means that automatic merges usually work just fine.  No system will help if different people are doing conflicting things.  What differing experiences have you had?

Answer (score 2):

VCS, can be used in lock-model (and merge, if wanted)

- SVN
- Plastic SCM

(if we say "...in BEST category...")

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend Perforce, it has a locking mechanism.

I see the anti-locking comments appearing on this thread already, but if your heart is set on locking, Perforce offers a central server where you can track who has which files locked.  There's an upgrade path if/when you decide against locking, because it also has a robust merging and integration system.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look. Ideally I would prefer locking yes.

Comment: @Dylan - beware of serious costs of Perforce.